# UIView on top of a UITableView when cell is clicked?

Tags: ios, uitableview

What I am trying to do is display a `smaller view` on top of a `UITableView` when a UITableViewCell is clicked. I don't want to transition to another UIViewController but "`popup`" a view on top of the UITableView that will house more information about the UITableViewCell clicked.

I don't think I am looking for a UIAlertView, but I am looking for a UIView that I can put labels, buttons, pictures, etc. on.

I hope my terminology is correct. I am still a newb :)

Leon

p.s. All my searching just came up with UIAlertView stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate function of the UITableView, the code is untested to give you an idea:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Assuming view is at zero index of XIB file.
    // this view will contain all lable and other controls
    UIView *customView = (UIView *)[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NameOfCustomViewXIBFile" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

    customView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.0f, 0.0f);
    [self.view addSubView:customView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:
                  ^{
                          customView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 1.0f);
                       }
    ];   
}
```

Hope it helps!

---

**EDIT:**

Animation to remove this popup:

```
    customView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 1.0f);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:
                  ^{
                          customView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.0f, 0.0f);
                       }
    ];   
    [customView removeFromSuperView];
```

Comment: This was very helpful. So were the other answers!
My question now is how do I go back to just displaying the table view? I want to be able to just click off of the popup view and have it not be displayed and destroyed.

Comment: google the touch handlings of a UIView `touchesbegin` and `touchesEnded` and find the location of touches and do the same animation in the reverse order. first Make scale 1, do animation and inside make scale to zero then instead of `addsubview` use `removeFromSuperView`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the existing answer is that if the user scrolls the table so that the cell goes offscreen and back on, the view that you popped up is likely to be gone due to cell re-use. To avoid this, you must store something in the cell's "model" so that every time cellForRowAtIndexPath: is called, you re-generate the cell with its popup view if it is supposed to be there. Just displaying from didSelectRowAtIndexPath: may be insufficient.

The approach I'd prefer for this if I were coding it is to make all the cells your own subclass of UITableViewCell. This subclass includes an extra BOOL showPopup. In your setter setShowPopup: you set the value, and also create & show or destroy/remove/hide the "popup" subview for that cell. (You could make the subview a class member that's always around, allocate and assign it when needed, and keep a reference, just showing/hiding as needed; that's a size/space performance trade-off.)

```
-(void) setShowPopup:(BOOL show) {
    showPopup = show;
    if(show) {
        // create subview, and add to view
    } else {
        // remove and destroy subview
    }
}
```

And in UITableView delegate/datasource:

```
-(UITableViewCell) UITableView:(UITableView *table) cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *ip) {
    // usual stuff to get a reusable cell or allocate a new one, and prepare it for display
    // then
    if(showPopup) {
       // create subview and add to view
    }   else {
       // remove and destroy subview
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a UIButton for something similar in a GLKViewController so this might work for a UITableViewController.  I just disabled the button and added a rounded border so it looked like a custom popup.  When the user clicked on something interesting, I changed the hidden flag on the button to show or hide it.

Something like this to make it look pop-up-y

In viewDidLoad:

```
// make info "popup"
_infoBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
_infoBtn.bounds = CGRectMake( 0, 0, kRightButtonBarDim, kRightButtonBarDim);
_infoBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.75];
_infoBtn.selected = NO;
_infoBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:kTableCellFontSize];
_infoBtn.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
[_infoBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:.3 alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];

// border
_infoBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 5;                             // rounded corners

// drop shadow
_infoBtn.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
_infoBtn.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
_infoBtn.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
_infoBtn.layer.shadowRadius = 12;
_infoBtn.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(12.0f, 12.0f);

_infoBtn.enabled = NO;
_infoBtn.hidden = YES;

[self.view addSubview:_infoBtn];
```

Then in tableView's didSelectRowAtIndexPath update any information needed in the button and set hidden to NO.  You should be able to add any necessary subviews to this UIButton.

```
_infoBtn.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 20, 20);    // set this wherever you like
[_infoBtn setTitle:@"text" forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
_infoBtn.hidden = NO;
```

I just tested this for a UIViewController that has a UITableView as a subview and it looked the same.  Scrolling did not affect it (i.e., the button did not move with scrolling, almost like a HUD) because the button was added to the top-level UIView.  Dunno if this is what you need, but hopefully it will give you some ideas.